# CentOS 6.1 + Oracle Express 11g

Tags: networking, centos, oracle-11g

I have installed CentOS 6.1 and Oracle.

And then I closed the firewall, used the right Env

Typed

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe start and
```

inited OK

But, I can not use  "get Started"
(Firefox displayed: "Unable to connect http://localhost:8080/apex")

What shall I do ?

Comment: I'm sorry -- none of this makes any sense. Please copy and paste the commands you actually executed, the error messages you actually get, and what you expected to happen. If you're trying to connect to `localhost` make sure you have a web server of some sort listening on port `8080`: `netstat -anp` for help there.

Comment: hello. thank you for ur reply. i have just type "rpm -ivh ora***.rpm" only. and i type netstat -anp | grep 8080 , and no process listening 8080

Comment: Are you positive `/etc/init.d/oracle-xe` is supposed to start a web server on port `8080`?

Comment: Sorry. i am a beginner of oracle, i do not know about this. in my view, the oracle-xe rpm is installed okay. The RPM said it would be automatically start when i am log in. But i need the web login interface. and I don't know why i can't use it. but no error msg is displayed. Thx